# How to remove scrow follow javascript when screen width changes

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a JavaScript code which is going to go on a WordPress CMS in the index.php file of my theme (see javascript code below). I have succeeded in making the scroll work, but when I resize the window (when the responsiveness sets in) the banner goes all the way to the left of my screen. I had thought that by disabling the JavaScript with a plain div tag, the responsiveness work. So I figured out that if I disable the JavaScript  at that point when the width of the containing tag was less than 600 I could make it work (by simply removing the JavaScript). It does not work.

I am not sure that the JavaScript solution is the best solution.  Can anyone help? Any suggestions will be welcomed...

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $sidebar = $(".follow-scroll"),
        $window = $(window),
        offset = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 20;
    $window.scroll(function () {
        //disable javascript if width larget less than 600
        if ($('.outern').width() < 600) {
            return;
        } else {
            //enable scroll folowing feature otherwise
            if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 20
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: You could also simplify your code by using something such as `if($(document).width()>600){ //enable scroll following feature }`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) listens for when the windows width/height changes.

Comment: do you mean that I should use resize instead? how?